# Prove $\operatorname{sgn}(\pi) = (-1)^r$ where $r$ is the number of inversions.

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, symmetric-groups

EDIT:

PROOF BY INDUCTION: If there are no inversions then we have an identity permutation, so the base case holds.

INDUCTIVE STEP : Lets fix some $r \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ and take any $\pi \in S_n$. If $\pi$ is the composition of inversions then $sgn(\pi) = (-1)^r$.

Fix some $\pi \in S_n$ then $\pi$ can be written as a composition of r+1 inversions. Lets say it can be written as follows :

$$\pi = (a_0 a_0')\circ(a_1 a_1')\circ \dots \circ(a_r a_r')$$

And lets say

$$\pi' =  (a_1 a_1')\circ \dots \circ(a_r a_r')$$

And the induction hypothesis satisfies $sgn(\pi') = (-1)^r$

But $\pi = (a_0 a_0') \circ \pi'$

And we know as a fact that $sgn((i j) \circ \pi) = -sgn(\pi)$. Which implies
$$sgn(\pi) =  -sgn(\pi')$$
$$sgn(\pi) = -(-1)^r = (-1)^{r+1} \quad \square$$

Comment: What exact definition for $\text{sgn}(\pi)$ are you using? Because what you are proving is a common *definition* for it (given with an accompanying theorem that it doesn't matter how $\pi$ is expressed as a composition of inversions.

Comment: Starting where you say "Suppose $\pi' = ...$", your proof makes no sense at all that I can figure out. What is "a one inversion"?. What is supposed to be equal to that next expression? Certainly not $\pi, \pi'$, or $\pi''$, except perhaps by chance. Why can the the signs of each part be written in the indicated form?  You've not justified this at all. Further, your previous expression has four "parts", but you reduce it to only two sign values. How?

Comment: I see what do you mean and I can see the faults in the proof too. But nevertheless what I was trying to do is first just write $\pi$ as a composition for transposition and a permutation. Since I don't say anything about the permutation $\pi '$ is so I write it in a similar way as I did with $\pi$. And I explicitly mention one inversion because that's what is left for me to show the induction as I already showed it for $k$. But I think that's the problem it can't be necessarily equal to $\pi$.

Comment: I am using $sgn({\pi}) = (-1)^r$, where $r$ is the number of inversions, for the definition of the sign. Same as the question statement.

Comment: You clearly have no clue what is going on here. You are trying to prove *your definition*?? Definitions do not need to be proved. They introduce something new, so there is no earlier results for that thing to prove the definition from. The only thing that needs to be proved for a definition is that it is consistent. Here, that is the proof that the sign is the same no matter how $\pi$ is a expressed as a product of transpositions (there are always multiple ways of doing so). This is more than can be corrected in a forum. Everything is messed up.

Comment: As you mentioned previously I know what is wrong with the proof. Maybe if there is some other fact that you would use yourself to prove $sgn(\pi) = (-1)^r$, would be helpful, at least it would help to start over the proof. Or any other thing.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what part of "Definitions do not need proved" did you not understand? If that is your definition, there is nothing to prove here.

Comment: One would need to know that the various expressions of the permutation all have the same parity, for this "definition" to be well-defined! The induction step also does not quite work, for this reason... depending on the logical ordering of things, of course.

Comment: So what I am missing there? As you mentioned that there are other expressions of permutation which give the same parity. two of them : $sgn(\pi) = (-1)^k$ where $k$ is the number of transpositions. $sgn(\pi) = (-1)^k$ where $k$ is the number of even cycles. should I use them in some way ?